# Computing: $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_\Bbb R n\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)^a\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R_+$ be measurable function such that $$\int_\Bbb Rf(x)dx = c$$

Then compute $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_\Bbb R n\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)^a\right) dx$$

Where $a>0 $ is  a parameter. My feeling is that this limit should be $\int_\Bbb Rf(x)dx = c$ but i don't have any good justification so far. any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinguish between the cases $\alpha<1,\alpha=1, \alpha>1$.

For $\alpha=1$ use $n\ln\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)=\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)^n\right)$ and $\left(1+\frac{y}{n}\right)^n\rightarrow e^y$ monotone for $y\geq 0$. Then use monotone convergence to pull the limit under the integral.

For $\alpha>1$ you can estimate the integral by the preceding. Then use dominated convergence to pull the limit under the integral to show that the integral is 0.

For $\alpha<1$ use Fatous lemma to show that the integral is $\infty$.